# Swift unit testing a method that includes timer

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer, swift5

I am new in swift and unit testing in swift. Here in the code in MyClass I am using timer to trigger some method ..
I need to do unit testing for that method that has timer count value..
I have checked few answers. nothing worked out.
I am unable to do that. Can anyone help me out with this.
Thanks in advance.

```
 class MyClass(){

func triggerSecondTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(repeatSecondTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func repeatSecondTimer(){
    timerCount += 1
    if isServiceCallComplete || timerCount == secondInterval {
        timer?.invalidate()
        finishedSecondTimer()
    }
}
}
   func testSecondTimer() {

    splashScreenMock.triggerSecondTimer()
   // I want to check the timer count here..

    XCTAssertEqual(self.splashScreenMock.timerCount, 20)


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use expectation.

for example:

```
func testSecondTimer() {
    let myObj = MyClass()
    let expectation = self.expectation(description: #function)
    let expectedTime: Double = 2

    myObj.triggerSecondTimer()
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + expectedTime) {
        expectation.fulfill()
    }

    waitForExpectations(timeout: expectedTime+1)
    XCTAssertEqual(myObj.timerCount, Int(expectedTime))
}
```

if in repeatSecondTimer method timerCount increase more than one, this test fails...

Answer (score 0):

What is it that you want to test here? You definitely shouldn't be testing the working mechanism of `Timer`. What you should be testing is that your code is configuring the timer correctly.

You can assume, for your testing purposes, that `Timer` works.

So...

Test that `timer.timeInterval` is correct, test that `timer.target` is correct, test that `timer.selector` is correct, and test any other properties that you need to ensure are set up properly.

You don't need to actually run the timer and wait a second and then check the correct function is run. That would be testing the inner workings of `Timer`.